# Why I cannot get rid of row.names in a data.frame in R?

Tags: r, rows, names

This problem is driving me crazy. I am reading from a .text file that was stored by write.table function, in which it was explicitly specified that row.names=F. I open the save file and check; yes, there are no row names. Then I use read.table to read in the data. Row.names appear.

I have tried the following four ways to get rid of the row.names, but none of them works.

```
trainval = read.table(file="processed_trainval.txt", header=T, row.names=NULL)
rownames(trainval) = NULL
row.names(trainval) = NULL
trainval = data.frame(trainval, row.names=NULL)
```

Every time I use

```
length(row.names(trainval))
```

to check, it's gives me the number of rows in my data.frame. What have I done wrong?

Comment: Please include some of the data.  What are the row names exactly?

Comment: by default rownames or row.names will return index of number of rows of your dataframe, if they don't have rownames. do row.names(trainval) and check output. the last "rowname" should match the nrow(trainval). "rowname" in quotes as it will be a character

Comment: Thank you so much infominer. I understand what's wrong: I should not have used length(row.names(trainval)) to check if rownames are there. Even if they are not, R will just add row index and it looks like it has rownames. A foolish mistake!

Comment: Dataframes have rownames. It's part of the class. If you just want lists, then just use 'list', or define another class and create functions to process..